# Display spinner only on the last page of Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have 3 fragments in my viewpager and I want to show a spinner item on my toolbar's menu on the last page. So if I am going from 2 -> 3 the spinner should become visible but if I go from 3 -> 2, it should become invisible. I know I have to add an `onPageChangeListener` to the viewpager but I am not sure how to determine which was the last page. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **MainActivity** where you have used **ViewPager** use below method

```
  //visible spinner when 3rd fragment is visible
                viewPagerFloor.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        if(position==2){
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else{
                         spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                         }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: *facepalm* How did I not think of that!? There's a slight problem with this though - the spinner shows up on the first page when the activity starts but disappears when I scroll to the second page. I tried setting the default visibility of the spinner item to false but then it does not show up even on the last page for some reason.

Comment: Also this crashes on rotation because `onCreateOptionsMenu()` hasn't been called so `spinner` is null

Comment: add spinner in toolbar not in menu. i am already using this code. provide me some more code so i can help you add you layout file and activity file in question

Comment: Yeah, I added it inside the toolbar's layout and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @jL4 Love to help you friend..enjoy coding